# jquery xml parsing approach

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, highcharts

We are working on creating a demo using highcharts. We are planning to get the data in xml format. The structure of this xml is not going to be fixed. Basically XML is supposed to represent raw data in tabular format. So if a table is containing columns A, B, C, D then xml will contain a node that will represent a row in the table. To parse an XML in jquery you need to know the tag name (as per my knowledge) but in this case I might not be knowing what the tag names are because in one case table may contain columns A,B,C,D and in other case it may contain columns T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z. Then how can I process such an xml and provide data to the chart? Any guidance, suggestions are most welcome. :)

```
e.g. in one case xml wil be - 
<record>-----there will be many such records
<A>...</A>
<B>...</B>
<C>...</C>
</record>
.
.
.
and in other case it can be - 

<record>-----there will be many such records
<u>...</u>
<v>...</v>
<w>...</w>
</record>
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just use `$('record').children()` to get a jQuery collection of the children nodes, whatever they may be.

Answer (score 0):

OK disclaimer: I don't know if you can use jQuery for this, or if it will work. So I'm answering this as a general DOM traversal question, as if it *does* work then this will apply.

**As far as I know:**
You don't need any tag names, barring perhaps the parent or top-level tagname.

jQuery has alot of very useful and advanced DOM traversal methods that can help - such as:

```
$.children();
$.siblings();
$.next();
$.prev();
$.parent();
$.parents();
$.closest();
$.andSelf();
$.not();
```

The `$.find('selector');` method is also pretty damn good if you know what you're looking for.

So an example might be:

```
var r1 = $('record').children(); //returns all child nodes of all <record> tags
var r2 = $('record'); //gets all records
var r3 = r2.children(); //the children of other records
```

Not sure how closely that fits your use case, but you can read up more on DOM traversal here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Hope this helps